# Django: Static files are not found

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add some static files to my project. I have tried adding a static folder to my app.

I have two apps:

1. Authentication (authn),
2. Main (main).

I have a lot of CSS/js content and I don't really know which is the best method to save the files, maybe all static files should be in one directory 'staticfiles' or each app should have 'static' folder. I have tried adding static folder to one of my apps, at this time - `authn`. And by trying to load the static files I firstly did `python manage.py collectstatic`, that put my all files into one folder, but I got two different folders now - admin, main. After tried putting all my static files into a static folder in `authn` app, but the static files were not loading after that. Here are my project structure and some photos and logs of the console, pycharm.
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make `static` folder outside the app
2. inside `static` create two folder `main` and `auth`
3. inside `main` and `auth` create `css` `js` `img` and another catagories of folder
4. Put each app's static file into their folder.That is put `main` app's css into `static/main/css/main.css` like that
5. In `settings.py` make some changes-

   ```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   ```

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), ]`

Comment: Everything works, but the main problem was that the name of the folder was auth...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add authn's static to STATICFILES_DIRS. [Detail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS)

```
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
  os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static'),
  os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'authn', 'static')
]
```

Comment: Hey, nothing happened.